# SharePoint 2010 - User Profile Application Proxy issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

Again I hope that some of you have already found a solution for my problem. Here is my environment:

- 2 front-end server with NLB
- 2 SQL Server (cluster)

While installing a third front end server for search and crawl jobs, we had to apply some hotfix and language pack on our two existing front end server. As we are using NLB we have installed the updates on one server first, and then the second one. And here comes the problem...

Both server are now with the same level of hotfix and language pack, but one server is up and running whereas the second one has the following issue when accessing to our redirection page (that use the User Profile Application) :
`Could not load user profile` and in the SharePoint log : 
`User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application` We have also this issue when accessing mysite and search engine.

I have searched all over internet for solutions, and I have check my administrators / permissions rights on the User Profile Application Service.

What I cannot explain is why this is working for one of our server but not for the other one.

Can you help me on this issue guys? Maybe you have already face this kind of issue in a past life!

Jordan

Comment: I had the same issue a while back, I am guessing the server running your services (User Profile Service is the one having issues). Check that the Forefront Identity services are running on the server.

Comment: Already check that and services are running (on the server that hold the User Profile Synchronization) but thanks